# Sequelize table validation and stop creating table

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize ORM in nodejs. I have two apps. One app is only for database related task like creating tables and migrations (app1). Other app is rest api (app2). I am using sequelize in app2.I dont want to create table using app2 and i want to throw error here if table doesnt exist or schema is not the same. Is this possible using sequelize?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to create the table in your app2, then just dont put the `sequelize.sync()` code. (if you're using migration and the sequelize-cli, then dont do `sequelize db:update` before launching your app2)

Concerning the error, if a table is not created, you will have errors when trying to use the schema ! 
I don't think there is a "clean" way of checking if the schema is inline with yours.